# Avoid .net win application setup on multiple machine

Tags: .net, winforms

We have windows application developed in .net & Currently it is deployed on multiple machine at client location.

If we have any changes in application then we need to deploy it on multiple location (by providing dll,exe etc files) but Customer (even we required as many customer is at remote place) required something like we install setup at one location (like on server) & all other machine will automatically have copy of it. Or something should be like client/server application

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you look at ClickOnce. It can provide automatic application updates for all client machines when you publish a new version.

See here for more information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx

Comment: This is helpful comments. By any chance you know how to have silent installation without prompting user to deploy it ?

Comment: @SushilJadhav You can also check for updates programmatically using ClickOnce. [How to: Check for Application Updates Programmatically Using the ClickOnce Deployment API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx)